# Getting null elements using xelement with c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

Let us consider the following xml document:

```
<contact>
    <name>Hines</name>
    <phone>206-555-0144</phone>
    <mobile>425-555-0145</mobile>
</contact>
```

from which I retrieve a value as

```
var value = parent.Element("name").Value;
```

The code above will throw a `NullReferenceException` if "name" is not present, as Element will return null in C# but not in vb.net which will throw empty value.

So my problem is to identify when the xml nodes below the root node are missing and to get an empty value instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create an extension method that can easily be reused. Place it in a static class

```
public static string ElementValue(this XElement parent, string elementName)
{
    var xel = parent.Element(elementName);
    return xel == null ? "" : xel.Value;
}
```

Now you can call it like this

```
string result = parent.ElementValue("name");
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you return `null` instead of an empty string when the element is not present, this gives you the possibility to differentiate between an empty element and the absence of an element.

```
public static string ElementValue(this XElement parent, string elementName)
{
    var xel = parent.Element(elementName);
    return xel == null ? null : xel.Value;
}
```

```
string result = parent.ElementValue("name");
if (result == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("Element 'name' is missing!");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}", result);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Microsoft uses the following pattern in different places in the .NET Framework Class Library

```
public static bool TryGetValue(this XElement parent, string elementName,
                                                     out string value)
{
    var xel = parent.Element(elementName);
    if (xel == null) {
        value = null;
        return false;
    }
    value = xel.Value;
    return true;
}
```

It can be called like this

```
string result;
if (parent.TryGetValue("name", out result)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}", result);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

With C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015) Microsoft has introduced the null propagation operator `?.` simplifying things a lot:

```
var value = parent.Element("name")?.Value;
```

This will simply set the value to null even if the element was not found.

You can also combine it with the coalesce operator `??`, if you want to return another value than `null`:

```
var value = parent.Element("name")?.Value ?? "";
```

Comment: thanks if ur code will return null if not present and return value if present am i right

Answer (score 4):

Simply cast your element to some nullable type. XElement has a [bunch of overloaded explicit casting operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx), which will cast elements value to required type:

```
string value = (string)parent.Element("name");
```

In this case if element `<name>` will not be found, you will get string with value equal to `null`. **NullReferenceException will not be raised**.

I think if element not exist in xml, then `null` is the only appropriate value for that element. But if you really need to have empty string instead, then:

```
string value = (string)parent.Element("name") ?? "";
```

Comment: +1. Very elegant solution. The only propblem with these castings is that intellisense does not reveal their presence :-(

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks! Yep, it took me some time to get used to casting of elements and attributes. But it really convenient!

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = parent.Element("name") != null ? parent.Element("name").Value : ""
```

Comment: thanks how can i respesent in boolean as if true value or element is present or false